# Font awesome icon not showing

Tags: html, css

I've used the font awesome icon to the `.playpause` class.

I have initialized the font awesome cdn as below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

But the font was not showing.

[Example Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/425gqLjv/)

Comment: Change .playpause into .playpause:after in your CSS

Comment: Alternatively use `<i class="fa fa-play"></i>` inside your `.playpause`-Element. Also reduces CSS by a little bit.

Comment: Including the [font-awesome CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/425gqLjv/16/) as an external resource might help... With `:before` after `.playhouse` in the CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `content:'';` with `:after` or `:before` pseudo element.

> The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after
>   pseudo-elements to generate content in an element. Objects inserted
>   using the content property are anonymous replaced elements.

[CDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

```
.playpause:after {
   content:'';
}
```

```css
video {
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: inherit;
    height: 450px;
}
.video-part{
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
}
.playpause:after {
    content: "\f04b";
    color: red;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    right:0%;
    top:0%;
    bottom:0%;
    margin:auto;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position: center;
    z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="video-part">
    <video class="video" poster="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcThj0RbBbtQjY5QXTbF5SNN33KQ6LXpRWN_mvXyKf4PDbOi3jk7EQ">
        <source src="sources/denvermnts.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  <div class="playpause"></div>
</div>
```